# Executing multiple statements in a single roundtrip with Informix

Tags: ado.net, informix

Is it possible to run multiple DML statements in a single roundtrip using Informix and .Net?

Example (of course this doesn't work):

```
var cmd = someIfxConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = @"
    insert into Foo(Bar, Baz) values (1, 2);
    insert into Foo(Bar, Baz) values (3, 4);";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I don't see why not. Did you try ?

Comment: @Xavinou: I'm the biggest idiot ever. It does work :-) Probably I tried something similar-but-invalid and assumed it wasn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, Informix allows you to perform multiple INSERT/UPDATE statements as you have in your example. What you CANNOT do is perform multiple statements that contain a SELECT.

For example, in SQL Server it is common to see code as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Foo(Bar, Baz) VALUES (1, 2); SELECT @@IDENTITY AS Id
```

This can be performed in a single command and would return the auto-incrementing primary key value from the newly inserted record.

This does not work within Informix however. You have to perform two distinct SQL commands. One to insert the record and one to retrieve the Id from the systables table:

```
SELECT DBINFO('sqlca.sqlerrd1') FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1
```